# how to add MBUnit test to CruiseControl.Net config file

Tags: mbunit

how to add MBUnit(tag) test to `CruiseControl.Net` config file.

Thanks,
Raja S

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking to run MbUnit tests from CCNet?

If you are already using NAnt or MSBuild to compile your code, then I would recommend that you just use the MbUnit or Gallio tasks from those same scripts.  The advantage is that you can also then run your tests on your developer machine without involving CCNet (assuming you use the same scripts there).

Another option is to use the CCNet  task to run MbUnit.Console.exe or Gallio.Echo.exe to run your tests.

BTW, Gallio includes instructions on how to configure the CCNet dashboard to display test results.